# How can I include mobile device details in headers when making a request?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to make a request to a web page and I've tried setting the view port to mobile device's as follows:

```
await page.setViewport({ width: 350, height: 700});
```

however, this doesn't get me the mobile site and instead I'm redirected to the desktop viewport site. When using chrome developer tools and I set it to iphone's viewport, I'm able to get the mobile version of the site.

Are there some headers I should be sending along with the age request in puppeteer to ensure I don't get redirected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might need to include `isMobile: true` in your viewport options ([`page.setViewport()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/38f112f/docs/api.md#pagesetviewportviewport)) and set the user agent ([`page.setUserAgent()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetuseragentuseragent)) to match a specific mobile device. Puppeteer provides a convenience method to do both automatically with [`page.emulate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageemulateoptions).

Example:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const devices = puppeteer.devices;
const iPhone = devices['iPhone 6'];

puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.emulate(iPhone);
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
  // other actions...
  await browser.close();
});
```

[demo](https://puppeteersandbox.com/IX3GNcEn)

Answer (score 5):

You can also open, see, edit and define this devices yourself by editing the following file.

```
/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DeviceDescriptor.js
```

you can see all available devices and select one of them or even define a custom one by yourself.

```
  {
    'name': 'CUSTOM NAME',
    'userAgent': 'any useragent options you want',
    'viewport': {
      'width': 1024,
      'height': 600,
      'deviceScaleFactor': 1,
      'isMobile': true,
      'hasTouch': true,
      'isLandscape': true
    }
  }
```

Just don't forget to

```
const devices = require('puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors'); 
const customDevice = devices['CUSTOM NAME'];

await page.emulate(customDevice);
```

Answer (score 4):

The API seems changed in v5. Here is how to do it now:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const phone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone X'];

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.emulate(phone);
await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
// other actions...
await browser.close();
```

Check official [API Doc](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.3.1&show=api-pageemulateoptions)

You can get all device names [here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/src/common/DeviceDescriptors.ts#L30-L954).

Comment: In recent versions, you need to use something like `const iPhone = KnownDevices['iPhone 6'];`

Answer (score 3):

You can launch chrome with a custom useragent as follows:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ['--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1'],
  });
```